# Is there any quick way to print in 3x3 matrix form?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, matrix

User can enter any value & the program will print the final matrix. Here I have used matrix addition to display the matrix in 3x3 form. I want to know is there any short way to still get our matrix in 3x3 form?

*Here's my code:*

```
print('Consider matrix mij with i rows & j colomns:')
a=int(input('Enter m11 value: '))
b=int(input('Enter m12 value: '))
c=int(input('Enter m13 value: '))
d=int(input('Enter m21 value: '))
e=int(input('Enter m22 value: '))
f=int(input('Enter m23 value: '))
g=int(input('Enter m31 value: '))
h=int(input('Enter m32 value: '))
i=int(input('Enter m33 value: '))
X=[[a,b,c],
   [d,e,f],
   [g,h,i]]
Y=[[0,0,0],
   [0,0,0],
   [0,0,0]]
print('Your matrix is:')
for i in range(len(X)):
    for j in range(len(X[0])):
        X[i][j]=X[i][j]+Y[i][j]
for r in X:
    print(r)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can use f-strings to achieve this.

```py
print(f"[{X[0][0]} {X[0][1]} {X[0][2]}]\n[{X[1][0]} {X[1][1]} {X[1][2]}]\n [{X[2][0]} {X[2][1]} {X[2][2]}]")
```

Take this sample:

```
f"[{X[0][0]} {X[0][1]} {X[0][2]}]\n"
```

Here, the values inside the `{}` are replaced by the expression inside. The `\n` acts as a special character which continues the print on a newline.

You can take inputs quicker using this code:

```py
X = [[input(f"Enter m{i}{j}: ") for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)]
```

This is called list comprehension and you can extend this to take as many values as you want.

Comment: Thanks, this worked as I wanted. The last line of your code should be [{X[2][0]} {X[2][1]} {X[2][2]}] though :P

Comment: Also is there any way to shorten the input codes? Like can we take all 9 inputs using any other way?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with little code too. I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
fm=list(map(int,input().split())) //first matrix
sm=list(map(int,input().split())) //second matrix
print("answer:")
for i in range(9):
    print(fm[i]+sm[i],end=' ')
    if i%3==2:
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution is using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
e=5
f=6
g=7
h=8
i=9
X=[[a,b,c],
   [d,e,f],
   [g,h,i]]

print(np.matrix(X))
```

the out put is:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

Comment: Worth noting the comment in [the documentation for np.matrix](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) *"It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future."*

Answer (score 0):

Use comprehension to compress your answer for example:
`[i for i in range[condition]]`

using comprehension may help you